# How to fix ArgumentError - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty: app/views/cars/new.html.erb:8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is what is get I when I go to **localhost:3000/cars/new**

```
ArgumentError - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty:
  app/views/cars/new.html.erb:8
```

What I have in my app/views/cars/new.html.erb **line 8**

```
<%= form_for @car do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `@car` in the controller:

```
def new
  @car=Car.new
end
```

Comment: I did that already but instead of @car=Car.new i did it like this @cars = current_user.cars.build

Comment: @Richard `@cars` or `@car` ?

Comment: Thanks @Viktor, it's working now. It should be car and not cars

Comment: @Richard That's why you should make sure to include all the relevant info. Usually it's the both the controller action and the view along with the full error message :) Glad you got it working

Comment: On a side note, "This is basic in ruby, you still have a long way to go.". This might be basic in Rails but definitely not in Ruby and I don't see how it adds any value to the answer.